# How to export html data into excel?

Tags: html, excel

I am  running queries and getting output in html format ,but when I copy it and paste it on excel sheet,data get disturbed .it spreads to infinite columns .
how can I restrict it?

Comment: Have you tried importing it using Excel's Get Data capabilities? Instead of copy paste, also - please provide more info - what queries? what does the html contain?

Comment: Can you provide more  info like .. some sample data ... how the html looks like ...etc .. some screen shots ..

Answer (score 1):

### **Solution:**

Please follow steps :

> 1. Copy html data
> 2. Paste it in excel (data looks scattered ,don't panic)
> 3. At the end of excel you will paste option.
> 4. Click on "**Text import wizard**" and click on **Delimited** option  and then select "**tab**" as delimiter and data will correctly formatted.

---

[image]